# Output of program of Function in C

Tags: c, function

It is simple program but i am confused about  the output of following program??

```
#include<stdio.h>
int fun(int);
int main()
{
    float k=3;
    fun(k=fun(fun(k)));
    printf("%f\n", k);
    return 0;
}
int fun(int i)
{
    i++;
    return i;
}
```

Comment: If you use a debugger and step through the program, you would learn a lot.

Comment: What is your expected output? What is the actual one?

Comment: Is the output is 5? What would you expect?

Comment: The output is 2,I guess

Comment: the output is 5.000000

Comment: What is the question? Are you asking why you are confused..? What output did you get when running the program and what did you expect?

Answer (score 1):

```
float k=3;
fun(k=fun(fun(k)));
printf("%f\n", k);
```

The important thing is what `k` gets sets to since that is what's being output.

That variable `k` is set by the *inner* assignment `k=fun(fun(k))`, which passes the original `k` of `3` to `fun()`, returning `4`.

Then *that* value `4` is passed to `fun()` again, returning `5`, which is what gets loaded into `k`.

The fact that `fun()` is called yet again is irrelevant here since the result of that is never used.

Answer (score 1):

Yeah you should use debugger and go step by step to see what it return every time.

The above program will return `5.000000`

```
float k=3;
fun(k=fun(fun(k)));
```

In this line your passing `fun()` with `k = 3.00000` which will go inside `fun()` where argument is int, so decimal values will not be considered and it will increment k by 1 and will return it.
again you have call `fun()` but now with the value 4 it will go to `fun()` again and will return 5.
then you have printed k with float `%f` since you declared it with float
so the output will be 5.000000

Comment: Well, *approximately* 5.000000-ish; still up-voting answer - clarity is good.

Comment: @frasnian, I'm pretty certain IEEE754 single precision floats can handle adding one to three twice and still maintain full precision, as well as convert very accurately between floats and ints in the integral range 3..5 inclusive :-)

Comment: @paxdiablo: You are more than correct, sir (/ maam): http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_floating_point#Directed_roundings. For what I typically do (financial calculations), I abandoned C/C++ float and double a long while back - I just want the C++ Standard to finally include Decimal types. Straight-up C Standard as well - the GNU extensions supporting this make me itchy.

Answer (score 0):

If you divide the line

```
fun(k=fun(fun(k)));
```

into multiple lines, it would be:

```
float temp = fun(k);
k = fun(temp);
fun(k);   // Return value is ignored.
```

Answer (score 0):

There are several things going on at once in the program, so it helps to deconstruct it slightly to understand what exactly is happening.

```
float k=3;
```

First, you define `float k` and set it to 3. That's pretty straightforward. Next:

```
fun(k=fun(fun(k)));
```

Let's breakdown this second line into several statements:

First, the innermost expression `fun(k)` is evaluated. This is actually a rather complicated operation, since k is a `float`, so in fact the first thing that goes on is k is implicitly truncated and converted to an integer type. Fortunately this gives a rather logical integer value of `3`. This argument of 3 is passed *by value* to the function `fun()`, which returns `4`.

This gives us a value that we can then use to evaluate the next step in our complicated little statement, which now effectively looks like this:

```
fun(k=fun(4));
```

Now `fun()` is called again, this time with an argument of 4 (the return type of `fun()` itself an integer, so we don't have to worry about any implicit type conversion this time). `fun(4)` returns 5.

Now our expression looks like this:

```
fun(k=5);
```

In C and C++, assignment expressions (that is, something that sets a variable to something, e.g. x = 10;) when evaluated return the value of the assignment. If we had just written:

```
k = 5;
```

An implicit conversion (again!) happens where the integer value of 5 is converted to a floating point value (e.g. 5.00000). This very thing happens inside `fun(k=5);`, but the *value* of the assignment expression, 5.0000, is used here as the argument to `fun()`! If you think this is confusing, it is; this is why the code as written would be considered bad style.

So finally there's a call to fun(5), but because the argument is passed *by value*, fun() runs, returns 6, but the result is not assigned to anything so this particular call has no effect.

Thus, when you go to print the variable `k`, it is still 5.0000 from when the second-to-last assignment statement `fun(k=5);` was evaluated.